# Return statement not exiting the function with the right value

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, function, return-value

I've made a function to do an iteration on all the controls in a form to check if a control name matches with a string. If it does, I would like to return the control itself as an object as the function value that is passed to the rest of the program.

Here's my work:

```
 Public Function getcontrolType(Optional ByVal controlString As String = "", Optional ByVal parentCtrl As Control = Nothing) As System.Object
    Dim returnValue As System.Object
    If parentCtrl Is Nothing Then
        parentCtrl = MainModelForm
    End If
    For Each ctrl As Control In parentCtrl.Controls
        If ctrl.HasChildren Then
            getcontrolType(controlString, ctrl)
        End If
        If ctrl.Name = controlString Then
            returnValue = ctrl.Name
            Return returnValue
        End If
    Next
    Return "Can't find control!"
End Function
```

The issue I'm running into is that the program executes correctly to the point of assigning the returnValue to the ctrl.Name, and then it executes the Return statement and then goes to the End Function. From there though, the code doesn't actually exit the function and instead jumps back to the getcontrolType(controlString, ctrl) line. I'm sure there has to be something off with my iteration (computers are only as smart as you tell them to be!), but I don't understand why it would go to the End Function line and then jump back into the code?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why it would go to the End Function line and then
>   jump back into the code?

This is to be expected. When a function returns, the execution goes back to the previous stack frame and resumes from where it left. This is exactly what your code does.

The confusing part comes from the fact that your function is recursive. You are under the impression that the code simply moves from the `Return` statement line back into a given position within code, similar to a `GOTO` operation. But truth is that the stack does in fact go down one frame, back to completing the previous call to the same function.

If you want to check this out, simply run your code in debug mode and watch the value of the `returnValue` variable. Right after the code "jumps back", you'll see that it will be pointing to a different value. This is because the execution is now back to completing the parent call, for which the value has been kept in memory.

In fact, that last part is actually one reason why you'd want to be very careful when making recursive calls. The deeper they go, the more memory they require. You can read about it here:

**[Recursive Procedures (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81tad23s.aspx)** - MSDN

As of **why your actual code doesn't work the way you want**, it looks like you never use the returned value of the nested call to `getcontrolType` function. Change that part to this instead:

```
If ctrl.HasChildren Then
    Return getcontrolType(controlString, ctrl)
End If
```

If I may, I would also suggest that you change your function's name to `GetControlName` and use `System.String` as the return type.

Or better yet: name it `GetControl` and have it return the instance of the found control (with return type being `System.Windows.Forms.Control`).

**EDIT:**

Are you aware of the [ControlCollection.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) method? It might give you what you want much more efficiently:

```
Dim controlToFind = parentControl.Controls.Find("myControlName", True).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I appreciate the in-depth explanation! It was getting pretty late by the time I threw that code together - so I assumed I was not thinking clearly about how the recursive call stack was working. I'll test this as soon as I can tomorrow at work and hopefully can mark this as answered - thanks again for the feedback!

Comment: @user3088949 See my edited answer. There's a built-in method within .NET to find nested controls that you might find useful.

Comment: I was not aware of that ControlCollection.Find method - I checked it out on the msdn and applied it appropriately. It definitely seemed to do the job. It needs some tweaking further down in the code but it is definitely easier to fix those issues now. Thanks again, I'll mark this as answered!